# How to solve gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(x) e^{-m(x-a)^2} dx $

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

$$\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(x) e^{-m(x-a)^2} dx$$

where $a$ and $m$ are constants. Is there an alternate way of solving this without using the Euler's formula or without breaking down sin into exponential form.

Comment: double integration by part.

Comment: Nothing gaussian here (and the integral always diverges).

Comment: what do we know about the variables?

Comment: $dx$ is missing!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes it is. Does this means the end of the world? What prevents you from editing the question?

Comment: so its dx, and a & m are constants....

Comment: i think not for each $a,m$ exist this integral

Comment: By the way, @abdulmoiz, you need $m>0$ as a hypothesis.

Comment: @Surb: How would double integration by parts help? You could get back to $\sin$, but there would also be the $x^2$ left over in the integrand in addition. That doesn't sound very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

$I=\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(x) e^{-m(x-a)^2} dx = \int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(X+a) e^{-m X^2} dX \quad $ with change of variable $x=X+a$

$I=\sin(a)\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \cos(X) e^{-m X^2} dX +\cos(a)\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(X) e^{-m X^2} dX$

$\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(X) e^{-m X^2} dX=0$

$\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \cos(X) e^{-m X^2} dX = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}}e^{-\frac{1}{4m}}$

$$\int_{-\infty} ^ \infty \sin(x) e^{-m(x-a)^2} dx =\sin(a)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}}e^{-\frac{1}{4m}}$$

Comment: thats a real neat way...

buts isnt this still using the value of cos from eular exponential form? i mean how can we do this without knowing the solution to the 2nd last step...

Answer (score 1):

I will postpone the question of convergence for now. Your (real-valued) integral is 
$$
S = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) e^{-m(x-a)^2} \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
$$
I assume that $m>0$. It can also be written using a complex exponential as
$$
S = \Im \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^ { ix - m(x-a)^2 } \, \mathrm{d} x   \right ] = \Im \left [ I \right ] \, ,
$$
where $I$ is the newly defined complex-values integral. Completing the square, I get
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ -m \left [ x - \left ( a + \frac{i}{2m} \right ) \right ]^2 + \left ( ia - \frac{1}{4m} \right ) } \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
$$
Changing variables to $y = x - \left ( a + \frac{i}{2m} \right )$,
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ -m y^2 + \left ( ia - \frac{1}{4m} \right ) } \, \mathrm{d} y  = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}} e^{ ia - \frac{1}{4m}} \, .
$$
Looking at the real and imaginary part separately, I get
$$
I = C + iS = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}} e^{-\frac{1}{4m}} \cos(a) + i \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}} e^{-\frac{1}{4m}} \sin(a) \, .
$$
**Result:**
Therefore it follows that
$$
S = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) e^ { - m(x-a)^2 } \, \mathrm{d} x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}} e^{-\frac{1}{4m}} \sin(a) \, ,
$$
and you get for free
$$
C = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(x) e^ {- m(x-a)^2 } \, \mathrm{d} x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m}} e^{-\frac{1}{4m}} \cos(a) \, .
$$

Comment: This does give the correct result, however there are some hidden details/unjustified assumptions here one should be aware off. The change of variables $y = x - (a+ib)$ makes the integral a complex integral and the integration is not along the real axis but along the line $z(t) = t - ib$ in the complex plane. The correctness of the result can be justified by using contour-integration.

Comment: Alternatively, make a change of coordinates to $y = x - a$, use the expansion for $\sin(y+a) = \cos(a) \sin(y)+ \sin(a) \cos(y)$ so that you have to evaluate $S = \sin(a) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(y) e^{-my^2} \, \mathrm{d} y$ (since the integral over the term involving $\sin(y)$ vanishes) then use the method given.

Comment: thats a neat way,, i also did something similar using the eular form of sin and cosine, but what i am interested in is doing this withour breaking down sin into an exponential...